# What is the process for transitioning to APNS Authentication Keys?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I've recently learned of the new APNS Authentication Key mechanism which is set to replace the functionality of the existing system of APNS certificates.

From my understanding this key supersedes all existing certificates, and can authenticate requests for all my apps.

I am confused about the transition though. Does this key only work for apps that are newly built/provisioned/released? My Firebase console invites me to upload my new APNS Authentication Key, but upon doing so, warns that my existing certificates which are being used in production will be removed. Does this mean my existing users will stop receiving push notifications?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, transitioning from certificate-based to authentication token-based only affects how your application server communicates with the APNS provider, thus existing users of your application will not be affected.